# Uppercase Last Couple Indexes of String Elements in Pandas Series

Tags: string, python-3.x, pandas, methods, series

I have the following pandas series:

```
test_series = pd.Series(['canton, nc', 'leicester, nc', 'asheville, nc', 'candler, nc',
       'marshall, nc', 'waynesville, nc', 'fletcher, nc',
       'hendersonville, nc', 'old fort, nc', 'horse shoe, nc',
       'black mountain, nc', 'maggie valley, nc', 'burnsville, nc',
       'weaverville, nc', 'zirconia, nc', 'swannanoa, nc',
       'hot springs, nc', 'arden, nc', 'east flat rock, nc', 'marion, nc',
       'mars hill, nc', 'flat rock, nc', 'rutherfordton, nc', 'clyde, nc',
       'saluda, nc', 'alexander, nc', 'fairview, nc', 'mill spring, nc',
       'brevard, nc', 'mills river, nc', 'penrose, nc',
       'pisgah forest, nc', 'barnardsville, nc', 'etowah, nc',
       'travelers rest, sc', 'lake lure, nc', 'montreat, nc', 'dana, nc',
       'greenville, sc', 'flag pond, tn', 'laurel park, nc'])
```

I would like to make the state accronyms uppercase.  This was my best guess: `test_series.str[-2:].upper()` but I get an attribute error. What would be the most efficient to do this?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

First select all values without last 2 and add to last 2 values converted to uppercase by [`str.upper`](http://pandas.pydata.org/pandas-docs/stable/generated/pandas.Series.str.upper.html):

```
test_series = test_series.str[:-2] + test_series.str[-2:].str.upper()
print (test_series.head())
0       canton, NC
1    leicester, NC
2    asheville, NC
3      candler, NC
4     marshall, NC
dtype: object
```

Answer (score 1):

For better performance use list comprehension and no NaNs in dataset:

```
test_series = pd.Series([i[:-2] + i[-2:].upper() for i in test_series])
```

Test for equilivance:

```
(test_series.str[:-2] + test_series.str[-2:].str.upper() == pd.Series([i[:-2] + i[-2:].upper() for i in test_series])).all()

 True
```

Timings:

```
%timeit test_series.str[:-2] + test_series.str[-2:].str.upper()
1000 loops, best of 3: 1.1 ms per loop

%timeit pd.Series([i[:-2] + i[-2:].upper() for i in test_series])
1000 loops, best of 3: 245 µs per loop
```

Output:

```
0             canton, NC
1          leicester, NC
2          asheville, NC
3            candler, NC
4           marshall, NC
5        waynesville, NC
6           fletcher, NC
7     hendersonville, NC
8           old fort, NC
9         horse shoe, NC
10    black mountain, NC
11     maggie valley, NC
12        burnsville, NC
13       weaverville, NC
14          zirconia, NC
15         swannanoa, NC
16       hot springs, NC
17             arden, NC
18    east flat rock, NC
19            marion, NC
20         mars hill, NC
21         flat rock, NC
22     rutherfordton, NC
23             clyde, NC
24            saluda, NC
25         alexander, NC
26          fairview, NC
27       mill spring, NC
28           brevard, NC
29       mills river, NC
30           penrose, NC
31     pisgah forest, NC
32     barnardsville, NC
33            etowah, NC
34    travelers rest, SC
35         lake lure, NC
36          montreat, NC
37              dana, NC
38        greenville, SC
39         flag pond, TN
40       laurel park, NC
dtype: object
```

Comment: Yes, but always is better use pandas `.str` solutions, because pure python failed if at least one `NaN`.